# How to separate two for loops in Apex code?

Tags: salesforce, apex

My code has two  for loops, which is inefficient and may hit governor limits. I want to separate the two for loops and still get the same result. How can I do that? Here is my code:

Here I wanted to check if **commissionPeriod** has the given **start** and **enddate** and also the selling role is contains in the set  of **Roles**.

The code i have running good but Not sure how to separate the two for loops for better efficiencies  where it may fail while comparing large set of data

```
//Create some CIP__c records
List<cip__c> cipRecords = new List<cip__c>();
cipRecords.add(new cip__c(StartDate__c = Date.newInstance(2023, 1, 1), EndDate__c = Date.newInstance(2023, 12, 31), SellingRole__c = 'Salesperson', PEKMapping__c = 'PEK1'));
cipRecords.add(new cip__c(StartDate__c = Date.newInstance(2023, 1, 1), EndDate__c = Date.newInstance(2023, 6, 30), SellingRole__c = 'MuleSfotAE', PEKMapping__c = 'PEK2'));

Set<String> Roles=new Set<String>();
Roles.add('Salesperson');
Roles.add('MuleSoftAE');
Roles.add('Sales Cloud');
Roles.add('Service Cloud');

//Create a set of unique commission periods
Set<Date> uniqueDates = new Set<Date>();
uniqueDates.add(Date.newInstance(2023, 1, 31));
uniqueDates.add(Date.newInstance(2023, 2, 28));
uniqueDates.add(Date.newInstance(2023, 3, 31));
uniqueDates.add(Date.newInstance(2023, 4, 30));
uniqueDates.add(Date.newInstance(2023, 5, 31));
uniqueDates.add(Date.newInstance(2023, 6, 30));
uniqueDates.add(Date.newInstance(2023, 7, 31));
uniqueDates.add(Date.newInstance(2023, 8, 31));
uniqueDates.add(Date.newInstance(2023, 9, 30));
uniqueDates.add(Date.newInstance(2023, 10, 31));
uniqueDates.add(Date.newInstance(2023, 11, 30));
uniqueDates.add(Date.newInstance(2023, 12, 31));

//Create a map of CPO Id to commission period
Map<Id, Date> cpowithDates = new Map<Id, Date>();
cpowithDates.put('001A00000123abc', Date.newInstance(2023, 1, 31));
cpowithDates.put('001A00000123def', Date.newInstance(2023, 2, 28));
cpowithDates.put('001A00000123ghi', Date.newInstance(2023, 3, 31));
cpowithDates.put('001A00000123jkl', Date.newInstance(2023, 4, 30));
cpowithDates.put('001A00000123mno', Date.newInstance(2023, 5, 31));
cpowithDates.put('001A00000123pqr', Date.newInstance(2023, 6, 30));


//Create an empty map of CPO Id to PEK mapping
Map<Id, String> cpoidToPekMap = new Map<Id, String>();
for (cip__c cipRecord: cipRecords)
{
    for(Id cpoIds:cpowithDates.keySet())
    {
        Date commissionPeriod = cpowithDates.get(cpoIds);
           if (cipRecord.StartDate__c <= commissionPeriod && cipRecord.EndDate__c >= commissionPeriod) 
           {
                if (Roles.contains(cipRecord.SellingRole__c))
                {
                    cpoidToPekMap.put(cpoids,cipRecord.PEKMapping__c);
                }
           }
    }
}
```

So is there a better way to achieve the same result by separating the two loops?

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't too bad, why do you think it'll hit governor limits? No SOQL in a loop (unless you anonymised it heavily), worst case it'll hit 10s Apex CPU time but I'd say unlikely. You could always turn it into a batch job and process even 1 `cip__c` at a time or make it loop over Accounts if you're concerned?

1. `uniqueDates` is initialised but not used anywhere. (unless you anonymised it - it's just "noise" wasting some CPU time and making it harder to understand what's going on)
2. I'd keep the main idea of 2 loops but flip the loops around. For each `cip__c` if it doesn't have a right role - it doesn't matter which dates match. That'd be a simple `contains` check and if you failed - just move on to next CIP. And if you passed - it's a "property" of the `cip__c` itself, not of the `cpowithDates`. So checking it in inner loop over and over when you know it'll always be same result is bit wasteful.
3. Can every Account (I mean the Ids start with `001...`) be in at most 1 commission scheme? You're putting them in a map but it's unclear what's the intention. Only 1 match possible or "last match wins"? If only 1 - you could gain some speed either removing matched ones from `cpowithDates` or adding 1 more check in inner loop whether `cpoidToPekMap` already contains this id. As code progresses it'll have less and less matches to run.

So something like

```apex
Map<Id, String> cpoidToPekMap = new Map<Id, String>();
for (cip__c cipRecord: cipRecords){
    if(roles.contains(cipRecord.SellingRole__c)){
        for(Id cpoIds: cpowithDates.keySet()){
            Date commissionPeriod = cpowithDates.get(cpoIds);
            if (cipRecord.StartDate__c <= commissionPeriod && cipRecord.EndDate__c >= commissionPeriod){
                cpoidToPekMap.put(cpoids,cipRecord.PEKMapping__c);
                cpowithDates.remove(cpoids);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4. Should be enough for your needs. If you really need to take it further... 1 trick would be to preprocess some stuff. If data is coming from queries - waste 1 query or loop to say determine min/max date for CIPs in right role and then query only accounts that are in that range. Crude but would count as prefilter.